# How to fix IndexError: list index out of range for this code

Tags: python

I am trying to create live rapidvideo links with the correct names.I found this code in github(https://github.com/robinjainher/kiss-gui-batch/blob/master/RV_downloader2.py) .But it gives a IndexError: list index out of range.The whole code can be found here (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robinjainher/kiss-gui-batch/master/RV_downloader2.py)

I would be glad if anyone can help me.Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your question includes no code; off-site links are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you

```
import bs4,requests,os

names = os.listdir()
b = []
for name in names:
   if('_RV.txt' in name):
      b.append(name)

for i in range(len(b)):
    print(str(i) + '  ' + b[i])

choice = int(input('Enter Choice : '))
name = b[choice]

#name = 'kono-koi-wa-tsumi-na-no-ka'
#name = input("Enter FileName : ")
quality = int(input("Enter Quality 
(0=480p,1=720p,2=1080p)"))
quality_t = '-480.mp4'
if quality == 1:
    quality_t = '-720.mp4'
elif quality == 2:
    quality_t = '-1080.mp4'
#def start():
file = open(name,'r')
a= file.read()
list2 = list(a.split('\n'))
file.close()

list_3 = []
list_4 = []

for url in list2:
   res = requests.get(url)
   if (str(res)!='<Response [404]>'):
       res.raise_for_status()
       soup =   bs4.BeautifulSoup
(res.text,features="lxml")
       elem = soup.select('a#button- 
       download')
    elem1= soup.select('strong')
    print(f"Downloading 
    {elem1[0].text}")


    if len(elem)==0:
        print('NOT FOUND')
    for i in range(len(elem)):
        try:
            if quality_t in elem[i].get('href'):

list_3.append(elem[quality].get('href'))

list_4.append(elem1[0].text)
                break
        except :
            print('Error',url)
else:
    print('404 Not Found '+url)
name = name.split('_')[0]
file = open(name+'_url.txt','w')
str3 = '\n'.join(list_3)
file.write(str3)
file.close()
file = open(name+'_N.txt','w')
str4 = '\n'.join(list_4)
file.write(str4)
file.close()
#start()

def get_url(url):
   res = requests.get(url)
   if (str(res) != '<Response [404]>'):
       res.raise_for_status()
       soup = 
bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 
features="lxml")
    elem = soup.select('a#button-download')
    elem1 = soup.select('strong')
    print(f"Downloading 
{elem1[0].text}")

    if len(elem1) == 0:
        print('NOT FOUND')
    for i in range(len(elem)):
        try:
            if quality_t in elem1[i].get('href'):
                list_3.append(elem1[quality].get('href'))
                list_4.append(elem1[0].text)
                break
        except:
            print('Error', url)
else:
    print('404 Not Found ' + url)
```